# How to define API endpoint for retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

This is my sample URL to the API end point:

`https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1/application?id=b0d5b503-eb2e-460a-b028-a3223aa93227&subscription-key=bc1cb297a94f4c9a9b58bcd36280466c&q=start%20test`

Now, how do I create the base URL and define end point for use in Retrofit.

I've created model class for `JSON`, and this is how I defined base URL:

```
    public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

This is how I tried to define the end point:

```
    public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("application")
    Call<LuisPojo> getValues(@Query("id") String apiKey);


}
```

But how to add the remaining part, `subscription-key` and the search term in the end

> start test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append it in your `getValues()`

```
@GET("application")
Call<LuisPojo> getValues(@Query("id") String apiKey, @Query("subscription-key") String key, @Query("q") String q);
```

Comment: That was very quick :D